# What is this C# structure

Tags: c#

I have come across the following code and am not sure what it means?

```
public class Countries
{
    public Countries();

    public static bool AllowInvoice(string pCountryCode);
    public static bool IsPostcodeMandatory(string pCountryCode);
}
```

This code is then called in the following way:

```
Contact.IncludePostCode = Countries.IsPostcodeMandatory(countryCode);
```

It seems to me that this is an interface? Where the method is being defined, but the body is being written elsewhere?

If this is the case, I would expect that when I search the whole project, I would find the code for the body of the method, but I do not find it anywhere?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you click "Go To Definition" and does it say "[From Metadata]" on that file?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes I did, but it leads back to itself

Comment: What @CodeCaster means is that this is not real, compilable code but just a representation of metadata. It only looks like code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This class is defined in a referenced assembly, Visual Studio is showing you the class's metadata.

What you see here are just the method signatures, not their implementation. This code would not compile.

Comment: how can I find out which DLL it is coming from?

Comment: It'll say so in the comment on top of the file. Otherwise try the Object Browser.